# javascript canvas round limitation and onclick variables

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have just started learning myself canvas, and so I have simple questions that Google could not answer me.

First of all, I have a canvas element which is 700px wide and 700px high. So the limitation for my canvas is a Rect. But I don't want it to be an Rect, I need a Circle. When using CSS only the styling changes.

My second question is about the events. I have a variable which draws a new object. If somebody clicks on the object, something should happen. But how can I click on the object, if it is not an element but a variable in javascript?

Thank you all so much!

Comment: [I can see CSS rules applies nicely to a canvas element](http://jsfiddle.net/ASBJZ/1/). So, I don't really get what you mean by "limitation" there

Comment: @Alexander You can still draw outside of the "bounds" of the border created with css. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/XQaUT/ and uncomment the call to `maskCanvas` before the rect is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS allow you to visually delimit the area of the code you are working on, the "border-radius" property does that for you. If your script requires specific mouse events inside the circle area, you can apply some basic math to decide wether the mouse is "inside" or "outside" your circle.

In the other hand, you cannot "click variables", but you can define empty elements (suck as  or  elements) with predefined height and width properties, binding the click event to it and then, associating the event with the variable in your script.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/XQaUT/1/

You can mask the canvas by using the `clip` function:

```
function maskCanvas(){
    ctx.beginPath(); 
    ctx.arc(rad, rad, rad, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);   
    ctx.clip();
}

maskCanvas();
```

You'll want to do this before drawing anything else to the canvas.

```
ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
```

The last `Path` you create is remembered by the canvas

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
ctx.arc(rad,rad,50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.fill();
```

so you can use `isPointInPath` to determine whether the mouse click is within that path.

```
canvas.onclick = function(e){
    console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(e.x,e.y));
};​
```